# Circular background of flutter widget as progressbar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

this is Antika. I have started learning to code since a few days back, and am only familiar with HTML/CSS/JS, and basics of **dart/flutter**

**Developer Level**: Beginner
**Project type & language**: I am developing a **Study planner app**  for myself, using **flutter**.

**Problem** - I have tried many ways to create a widget, that **has the details of the task**,**with a progress bar - like background**.

**SOMETHING LIKE THIS (WIDGET)-**

How do I create a Widget like this with flutter.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a code snippet what you have achieved so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinearProgressIndicator` can be wrapped with `SizedBox`.

```dart
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12), // have border decoration
    child: Stack(
      // you may need to wrap with sizedBOx
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          height: 100, //stack size, or use fit
          width: 400,
          child: LinearProgressIndicator(
            value: sliderValue,
          ),
        )

        //place your widget
      ],
    )),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```dart
final double _width = 300;
final double _height = 110;

return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: _width,
            height: _height,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
          Container(
            //0.74 is percentage
            width: _width * 0.74,
            height: _height,
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: _width,
            height: _height,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'BioWopin',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Due in 26 days',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Text(
                  '74%',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                )
              ],
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much ❤️. You made it so simple.   I was thinking of more and more complex ways. thinking of , but I did not realize it could be done simply like this.